# How to I redirect after login while using jwt authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, frontend

I have a Node.js backend server which uses JWT for authentication. While building the frontend for the app when I send a login request and receive the token I store it in the localStorage of the browser, after that I want to redirect to the dashboard but the problem I am facing is that since the dashboard route is protected it requires the token but Js redirect method doesn't allow any headers. So, how should I be tackling this problem ?

```
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

if (!localStorage.getItem("token"))
    localStorage.setItem("token", "");

submit.addEventListener('click' , (e) => {
   const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
   e.preventDefault();
   const data = {
      email,
      password
   }
   axios.post('/api/user/login', data)
      .then((res) => {
            document.getElementById('login_form').reset();
            console.log(res.data);
            if (res.data.success) {
               localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
               document.window.location.href = '/organizer/dashboard';
            }
         })
      .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err);
         })
});
```

The JSON received after a successful login request :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "token": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjViNTQzMWE1OTA0ZjkzMDQwOWM2OWU0NCIsIm5hbWUiOiJyYXNpayByYWoiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImZpc3J0QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImFjY190eXBlIjoib3JnYW5pc2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTMyMjQ4Mjc3LCJleHAiOjE1MzIyNTE4Nzd9.RHBMlVXXo-1YpwxnJbPdZ2VJ6Yt7aqTNJ3o6OzbXk4M"
}
```

Comment: Is dashboard a route from node?

Comment: @Ohjay44 yes, i m using a templating engine(hbs) for frontend

Comment: if you store your token as a secure cookie you can retrieve it from nodejs using a middleware

Comment: @Ohjay44 and then use that middleware to retrieve and add the token to each request header ?

Comment: yes, once you have a middleware you can use that in each route that you want the token required on. I have a custom middleware that I use. I can provide an example if you would like

Comment: @Ohjay44 Yeah, an example would be really helpful.

Comment: was my example helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a custom middleware and its usage.

Creating the token and setting it in a cookie:

```
function createAuthToken(id, agent, guidUser) {
    var sign = config[env].signature;
    var package = { 'device': id, 'access': 'authenticated', 'agent': agent, 'user': guidUser }
    return jwt.sign(package, sign, { expiresIn: '90 days' });
};

app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    var updatedToken = createAuthToken(body.device, body.userAgent, body.user);
    var newDate = new Date();
    var expDate = newDate.setMonth(newDate.getMonth() + 3)
    res.cookie('id', updatedToken, { sameSite: true, maxAge: expDate });
    res.send({ Success: true})
});
```

Middleware (Nodejs):

```
function authenticateRoute(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.cookies["id"];
    var sign = config[env].signature;

    jwt.verify(token, sign, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err || !decoded) {
            console.log("invalid token");
            res.send(403);
        }
        else if (decoded && (!decoded.access || decoded.access == "unauthenticated")) {
            console.log("unauthenticated token");
            res.send(403);
        }
        else if (decoded && decoded.access == "authenticated") {
            console.log("valid token")
            next();
        }
        else {
            console.log("something suspicious")
            res.send(403);
        }
    });
};
```

Then on all routes you want to use this authentication:

```
app.post('/authedcall', authenticateRoute, function (req, res) {
    res.send({ Success: true })
});

app.post('/unauthedcall', function (req, res) {
    res.send({ Success: true })
});
```

Authenticated Routes:

```
app.use('/loginroute', express.static(__dirname + "/login")); //no auth
app.use('/dashboard', authenticateRoute, express.static(__dirname + "/dash")); //auth route
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re looking for this....

```
 <Switch>
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
 </Switch>
```

You can wrap your private route in switch and then just put the path you want it to go if it’s authenticated and what component to load

Check this out this will be helpful
[privateroute](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/)

Comment: I am not using react, it's just vanilla javascript

Comment: Yikes, I don’t know why I thought you were using react. It makes this so much easier 